# How to label examples in Latex?

Tags: theorems

I have used the following code in Latex:

```
\begin{example}
Determine the integral 

\end{example}
```

However the words 'Determine the integral' appear in italics. How do I change this to appear as normal text not italics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe  it's because the _example_ environment is in math mode?

Comment: Please post your question with proper `MWE`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not possible to help you with this, since we don't know how the `example` environment is defined. Therefore, as already stated, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the document class and packages you use.

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble, add these lines :

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

You can find more information [on this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Theorems_and_proofs).